# How to use HFileOutputFormat class of HBase with Spark JavaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset?

Tags: hbase, apache-spark, bulk-load

I'm trying to bulk-load the content of a Spark JavaPairRDD to a HBase table.

It seems that using JavaPairRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataSet with HFileOutputFormat is the right way.

Is there an example code for that?

Comment: Could https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/HBaseTest.scala or https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/hbase_outputformat.py be of *any* help?

Answer (score 0):

Consider an RDD containing a single line :

```
{"id":3,"name":"Moony","color":"grey","description":"Monochrome kitty"}
```

**Transform the RDD** 
We neet to transform the RDD into a (key,value) pair having the following contents:

( rowkey , [ row key , column family , column name , value ] )

```
datamap = rdd.map(lambda x: (str(json.loads(x)["id"]),[str(json.loads(x)["id"]),"cfamily","cats_json",x]))
```

**Save to HBase**

We can make use of the `RDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset` function as used in this example: [PySpark Hbase example](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/hbase_outputformat.py) to save the RDD to HBase
?

```
datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv)
```

You can refer to my blog :[pyspark-sparkstreaming hbase](http://cjcroix.blogspot.in/2015/10/pyspark-hbase-and-spark-streaming-save.html) for the complete code of the working example.